# How to parse a java code to generate UML diagram?

Tags: java, parsing, uml, class-diagram

I mean I know there are tools which can do that automatically; but what if I have to manually build such parser to reverse engineer the java code into UML diagrams? what guidelines or grammar or steps would you recommend to build such parser in Java programming language, any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Sounds like too big a task if you even don't know where to start. Care to elaborate on why you want/need to do this?

Comment: I have written a compiler some 30 years ago. Believe me, you want a profound study at university before tackling this one.

Answer (score 2):

I use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to create parsers in Java. You might be able to use an existing grammar file with it (e.g. https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) - that way you should be able to build yourself a Java source file parser even without profound knowledge of grammars and parsers.